# JDBCClient errors on start or after some time in vertx

Tags: java, vert.x

[image: the error in question]

Excuse the picture of the terminal - my project setup is pretty bad so I can't get the actual logs to paste here.

Sometimes when I start up my vertx webserver and login, it does it absolutely fine with no issues. After some time, any database request (such as logging in again) will return this error. Sometimes this just happens on startup.

The `JDBCClient` is initialised on server load and I feel like the error could be to do with the AWS server it's connecting to giving it a timeout signal. Is there any way I can check for this and reinitialise the `JDBCClient` before making the request? Or is there another issue somewhere I don't know about?

Comment: Are you closing resultSet, Statement and Connection in the serial I wrote?

Comment: @Satya not too sure what you mean by this, SQLConnection is closed every time it's called

Comment: Can you add code where you are initializing JDBCClient and getting connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two causes of `RejectedExecutionException`

1. One of the causes of `RejectedExecutionException` is when we try to
   execute a new task after we’ve shutdown the executor.
2. Another case of `RejectedExecutionException`, appears when an Executor
   cannot take any more tasks under its responsibility. This happens
   when the limit of its local “memory” is reached.

In your case this exception is causing on line no `108` of `JDBCClientImpl.java` which is `exec.execute()`. Here `exec` is object of `ExecutorService` which is causing `RejectedExecutionException` because the task cannot be submitted for execution, either because this executor has been shutdown or because its capacity has been reached.

1. Check if you are `ResultSet`, `Statement` and `Connection` closing
   it or not.
2. Check if you are initializing `JDBCClientImpl` multiple times which
   may also cause this exception.
3. ThreadPoolExecutor has a [finalize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#finalize())  method that shuts down the
   executor. Given that we weren’t keeping a reference to the underling
   executor, it seemed like a strong possibility that finalization was
   causing the shutdown.

You can check out this url for [RejectedExecutionException](https://www.farside.org.uk/201309/learning_from_bad_code) and this [JDBCCLientImpl.java](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-jdbc-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/jdbc/impl/JDBCClientImpl.java) where you can find `getConnection()` method source.

Comment: In reference to no. 3, would this mean the problem is within vertx itself and not in my code?

Comment: In your code, If you are reinitializing JDBCClient then this might cause the problem. If you are not Using JDBCClient properly then your code might be causing the prblem.

Comment: In reference 3, I'm considering you are losing reference of executor in your code.